# Python script to open Notepad and write with pyautogui lib

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to create a script to open a webpage and to type stuff there, but first I wanted to try to do it using Notepad

```
import time
import os
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

os.system("notepad.exe")
#time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)
```

This is what I have so far. The problem is that it only opens the Notepad and only after I close the Notepad, 'Hello world!' is printed on my terminal where I'm running the script.

What am I missing here? Is there any other way to write text with a python script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is called file handling

```
 with open('Filename.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('What you want to put in')
```

But this also works

```
import time
import os
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as K
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as M

os.startfile("notepad.exe")
M().position = (900,400)
M().click(Button.left, 1)
#time.sleep(3)
K().type('Hello world!')
```

Comment: I know the file handling but my goal is to do another thing that doesn´t envolve files, so I just wanted to figure how to input from keyboard using python first, but yeah that's what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pyautogui's mouse functions to click the notepad and then type it. For more information on the mouse functions, go here:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/

Comment: Did it work? You might have to make sure that the notepad is on full-screen.